# Applying for other visas after Canadian visa refusal?

Tags: visas, transit, canada, visa-refusals

Hi my Canadian transit visa was refused because my travel itinerary didn't have my name on it. The embassy told me I can fix the issue and reapply again and my visa will be issued without any further problem.

**My question is will this refusal affect my future travel plans, as I am afraid this refusal will affect my record when applying for a US or Schengen visa?**

Also I have already applied for more than 2 US visas all of them were accepted and issued, this is the first time where I have a problem with a visa refusal.

Comment: Is this really a refusal? Sounds to me like a simple a request for further documentation or clarification of documentation provided, which is not a bad thing at all - it means that your application is likely to be approved (you were told as much) but the documentation provided was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will (at least slightly) impact future applications. As you write your visa was refused and there is no way around it. So in future applications (including but not limited to US, UK, Schengen), when asked, you will need to specify that you have previously been refused a visa (typically there is a box for explanations). However that is not a deal-breaker in itself if you have a good explanation and if the refusal has been fixed by re-applying with a good itinerary in your name and a subsequently granted visa.

Answer (score -2):

No, there is no affects occur on your future travel plan if your Canadian visa is refused. You have to simply fill all important information including your name and apply again. I think this is not a big issue. So don't worry about that.

Comment: So when i fill a form for a visa should i say that i had a previous visa refusal?

Comment: That's a very good question. In this case it would probably be good to correct the application and get the visa just so you have evidence that the visa was not ultimately refused to support continuing to answer that question with a "no".

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up this answer? In particular, visa application forms ask if you've previously been refused visas.

Comment: This is a wrong answer and as such it needs to be downvoted, but not deleted, following the rules of the site.

Comment: @pnuts, I found it in the review Q to delete because of low quality. Where it did not belong.

Answer (score -4):

There is no need to mention that you had a previous visa refusal. The consulate has access to your old record and they know the previous condition with you. So i don't think there is a need for such kind of information to be mentioned.

Comment: This seems to be _very_ bad advice. Part of the process of obtaining a visa is convincing the country you're visiting that you're honest: that you really are coming as a tourist (or whatever you said) and that you really will leave when you're done. Saying things that can be found to be false just by looking at records of past correspondence is a great way of convincing somebody that you're not honest. Dishonesty on applications is the sort of thing that results in refusals and bans.

Comment: This is a wrong answer, as such it needs to be down voted, but not deleted, according to the rules of the site.

Comment: [This person](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/refused-twice-for-uk-visa-second-time-under-3207a-deception) failed to mention that they had a previous refusal, and as a result they are unlikely to be able to enter the UK for about 10 years, and their sports career is in jeopardy.  So this is clearly not good advice in general.